# Flutter Firestore how to retrieve uid by entering email

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make a TextField where if I input an email it will display that email's UID

Here is the screenshot of my Firestore Database
[image: screenshot]

In the picture, the document ID is set as the UID for easier access.

Here is the code I have so far, which is not working

```
Widget _inputEmail() {
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return Container(
      width: 355,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: _email,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Email',
            helperText: 'Enter Email',
            suffixIcon: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
              onPressed: () async {
                if (_email == snapshot.data!.docs[0].id) {
                  print(user.uid);
                } else {
                  print('failed');
                }
              },
            ),
            border: UnderlineInputBorder()),
      ),
    );
  }
);
```

P.S the app is an e wallet app, and the code is for the transfer menu, so when the user input the recipient's email, they can modify the money data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use queries to get the document with that specific emails without fetching all the documents.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .where('email', isEqualTo: _email)
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) => print(snapshot.docs[0].data()['users ID']));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are only checking if the email entered matches the first document. You need to check if it matches an email in any of the documents, and only the email field, if I'm not mistaken. Try this out:

```
onPressed: () async {
                for(int i = 0; i < snapshot.data!.docs.length; i++){
                  if (_email == snapshot.data!.docs[i]["email"]) {
                  print(user.uid);
                } else {
                  print('email not found in document $i');
                }
                }
              },
```